# How to handle extended ASCII in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, non-ascii-characters

Just wondering how anyone has dealt with handling extended ASCII in hive. For example, characters like §.

I see that character in the raw data stored as string in Hive but once I query or export the data it does not show up properly. Is there anyway to retain the §?